# Webpack Dev Server Proxyconfig throwing Connection refused error

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-module-federation, angular-module-federation

We're using module federation to combine angularJS(8080) and Angular project(4201). Now to handle assets, I'm trying to use proxy to redirect assets location to my angular project, running on 4201. But I'm getting Connection Refused Error when I tried to load the screen with this config.
Both the project are Running and working fine individually.

I'm getting this error:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EVvYu.png)

This is the Dev Server, proxy config:
 `devServer: { static: [path.resolve(process.cwd(), "build")], hot: true, port: 8080, host: "localhost", liveReload: true, open: false, proxy: { "/gravty-members": { target: "http://localhost:4201/", pathRewrite: { "^/gravty-members": "" }, secure: false, changeOrigin: true, logLevel: "debug", }, }, },`

Webpack Version: 5.20.2
Angular Version: 14.2.0